# Set VNImageOptionCameraIntrinsics from ARCamera

Tags: ios, objective-c, arkit, coreml

I am building an application which combines ARKit with CoreML. I am passing frames to the `VNImageRequestHandler` using the following lines:

```
// the frame of the current Scene
CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = _cameraPreview.session.currentFrame.capturedImage;

NSMutableDictionary<VNImageOption, id> *requestOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
VNImageRequestHandler *handler = [[VNImageRequestHandler alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer options:requestOptions];
```

Note the `requestOptions`. It should contain the `VNImageOptionCameraIntrinsics` field which passes the camera intrinsics to CoreML.

Before using ARKit I was using a `CMSampleBufferRef` to get images from the camera. The instrinsics could be retrieved and set using the following:

```
CFTypeRef cameraIntrinsicData = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_CameraIntrinsicMatrix, nil);
requestOptions[VNImageOptionCameraIntrinsics] = (__bridge id)(cameraIntrinsicData);
```

However, I am using an `ARFrame` now, but I still want to set the correct intrinsics since the `pixelBuffer` is rotated.

Looking at the docs:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnimageoption?language=objc

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2875730-intrinsics?language=objc

We can see that `ARCamera` provides intrinsics as well, however, how do I set this value in the `requestOptions` properly?

So far it should be something like this:

```
ARCamera *camera = _cameraPreview.session.currentFrame.camera;
NSMutableDictionary<VNImageOption, id> *requestOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
// How to put camera.intrinsics here?
requestOptions[VNImageOptionCameraIntrinsics] = camera.intrinsics;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Giovanni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5457878/giovanni-terlingen) mentioned in the comments, converting `UIDeviceOrientation` to `CGImagePropertyOrientation` avoids the need to use `VNImageOptionCameraIntrinsics`:

[**Utils.m**](https://github.com/BlindAssist/blindassist-ios/blob/develop/BlindAssist/Utils.m)

```
+(CGImagePropertyOrientation) getOrientation {
    CGImagePropertyOrientation orientation;
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    switch (deviceOrientation) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            orientation = kCGImagePropertyOrientationRight;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            orientation = kCGImagePropertyOrientationLeft;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            orientation = kCGImagePropertyOrientationUp;
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            orientation = kCGImagePropertyOrientationDown;
            break;
        default:
            orientation = kCGImagePropertyOrientationRight;
            break;
    }
    return orientation;
}
```

[**ViewController.mm**](https://github.com/BlindAssist/blindassist-ios/blob/30fa5f0804d9b3f357c403b0875061027afc7dfb/BlindAssist/ViewController.mm#L166-L176)

```
- (void)captureOutput {
    ARFrame *frame = self.cameraPreview.session.currentFrame;
    CVPixelBufferRef pixelBuffer = frame.capturedImage;

    CGImagePropertyOrientation deviceOrientation = [Utils getOrientation];
    NSMutableDictionary<VNImageOption, id> *requestOptions = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    VNImageRequestHandler *handler = [[VNImageRequestHandler alloc] initWithCVPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer orientation:deviceOrientation options:requestOptions];

    [handler performRequests:@[[self request]] error:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However this is the old approach, you are using the sample buffer here, note that I want to use ARFrame instead.

Comment: Ah, yes sorry about that... I misread what you were trying to do. So If I understand correctly, you aren't able to use `ARFrame` with `VNImageOptionCameraInstrinsics`?

Comment: Exactly. I want to pass the correct information about the ARFrame/ARCamera to the VNImageRequestHandler.

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen: Apple has a [sample project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/using_vision_in_real_time_with_arkit?language=objc) (unfortunately in Swift only I believe) which might be useful. It appears they are suggesting to use create a session, then using the method [`session:didUpdateFrame:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessiondelegate/2865611-session?language=objc) and passing it to the request handler that way.

Comment: Thanks! Will take a look tomorrow.

Comment: I think setting the `CGImagePropertyOrientation` will do the trick. However I need to write some converter to convert the `UIDeviceOrientation` to a `CGImagePropertyOrientation` since it will be different in Objective-C

Comment: It worked. If you update your answer I will accept it :)

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen: Great, will do! I'm guessing that you didn't end up using `VNImageOptionCameraIntrinsics` and went with `VNImageRequestHandler` and the conversion to `CGImagePropertyOrientation` instead?

Comment: Yep, exactly! https://github.com/BlindAssist/blindassist-ios/blob/develop/BlindAssist/Utils.m#L15

Comment: @GiovanniTerlingen: Aha! Really all credit goes to you, so if you want to get the reputation and post your own answer I'll delete this one and upvote yours (totally up to you). You made it easy on me, and taught me something new in the process — cheers! :)